# Use of どうして　わかりましたか

Tags: questions

`どうして　わかりましたか。`

My teacher said this in a conversation and my brain translated it to *"Why did you understand?"* (which didn't make much sense given the context!) but I think what she meant was *"How did you notice?"*.

The context:

Me: 先生{せんせい}は　犬{いぬ}が　好{す}きですね。

Her: はい、好{す}きです。どうして　わかりましたか。

Am I understanding this correctly? If so, why did her question start with どうして instead of どう?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your teacher means 'Why did you know I like dogs?'
`わかる` means different things depending on context. Here it translates 'to know' as opposed to 'understand'.

As a language, Japanese is heavily tied to context. There are often different translations of the same word to English depending on the context.

Comment: Why どうして? Would どうわかりましたか be valid as well?

Comment: A Native Japanese speaker could understand `どう` but it is not *correct*.

Comment: You should try not connect a Japanese word with a particular English word. That is not how lanuages work. Many an  English word can be translated with several Japanese words, depensing on the context. Try to get a feeling for how a word works. Of course, this takes time, so don't feel bad because you can't do that yet. It also helps to consult a Japanese dictionary; here you would get the following definition for 分かる:「頭で考えたり、自分で経験したりして、正しい判断・理解が得られる」 You did not simply "know", you must have gained that knowledge somehow.